Netlify - Angular 18 SSR Deployment: 01J8B9TY error [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without ‘new’
Angular version: 18.0.2
Node version: 20.17.0
NPM version: 10.8.3
https://lebenslaufaideploy.netlify.app/
I have been getting this error in Netlify:
01J8B9TY error [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without ‘new’
i already googled and we should change in tsconfig.app.json “compilerOptions”: { “target”: “es6” }
I also tried es 2017, but still it didn’t help
When i run netlify dev, everything works perfectly fine locally
logs:
Sep 22, 12:04:21 AM: 01J8B9TK error  [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36171
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1601
    at new A (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/polyfills.server.mjs:4:2348)
    at K (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1421)
    at s4 (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36126)
    at default (file:///root/.netlify/edge-functions/angular-ssr/angular-ssr.mjs:11:24)
    at file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:425:15
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:231:13)
    at FunctionChain.runFunction (file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:419:28)Sep 22, 12:04:21 AM: 01J8B9TK info   [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36171
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1601
    at new A (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/polyfills.server.mjs:4:2348)
    at K (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1421)
    at s4 (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36126)
    at default (file:///root/.netlify/edge-functions/angular-ssr/angular-ssr.mjs:11:24)
    at file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:425:15
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:231:13)
    at FunctionChain.runFunction (file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:419:28)Sep 22, 12:04:33 AM: 01J8B9TY error  [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36171
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1601
    at new A (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/polyfills.server.mjs:4:2348)
    at K (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1421)
    at s4 (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36126)
    at default (file:///root/.netlify/edge-functions/angular-ssr/angular-ssr.mjs:11:24)
    at file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:425:15
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:231:13)
    at FunctionChain.runFunction (file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:419:28)Sep 22, 12:04:33 AM: 01J8B9TY info   [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36171
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1601
    at new A (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/polyfills.server.mjs:4:2348)
    at K (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1421)
    at s4 (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36126)
    at default (file:///root/.netlify/edge-functions/angular-ssr/angular-ssr.mjs:11:24)
    at file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:425:15
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:231:13)
    at FunctionChain.runFunction (file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:419:28)Sep 22, 12:04:33 AM: 01J8B9V0 error  [Angular SSR] TypeError: Class constructor e cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36171
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1601
    at new A (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/polyfills.server.mjs:4:2348)
    at K (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-NDYDZJSS.mjs:2:1421)
    at s4 (file:///root/dist/frontend/server/chunk-6FLYAFQ7.mjs:43:36126)
    at default (file:///root/.netlify/edge-functions/angular-ssr/angular-ssr.mjs:11:24)
    at file:///root/src/bootstrap/function_chain.ts:425:15
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:231:13)

if you need any more inforrmation, please contact me, repo is private, glady will add you to the project
i deployed it on netlify with netlify build --prod, opened the site
opened site
build run
netlify deploy --build --prod
already tried
-npm update
-changed tsconfig target to "es2017", es5, es6
